# Двойной клик на кнопку с задержкой

Tags: javascript

У меня есть кнопка, которая должна сработать, если нажать на неё два раза с задержкой не больше 300мс. Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать.

Comment: click + setTimeout в помощь

Comment: Для таких целей принято использовать событие `dbclick`

Comment: можно запоминать таймстемп клика, и при следующем клике его проверять

Answer (score 1):

По условию обязательно не более 300 мс? Иначе можно использовать dblclick, но задержка чуть больше.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
button.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
  alert('clicked!!!');
});
```

```html
<button class="button">click me</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Костыли конечно , может в ondblclick есть встроенная функция отслеживания интервала нажатия , но можно попробовать как то так:

```
 var s = true 
    function double() {
        event.preventDefault()
        s=!s
        setTimeout(()=>{
            s=!s
        },300)
        if(s){
            console.log('ok')
        }
    }
```